# memory exhausted: can not allocate memory error in raspberry pi

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, memory

I am trying to turn my raspberry to a PiCroft. For that I need to use these commands:

```
cd ~/
git clone https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-core.git
cd mycroft-core
bash dev_setup.sh
```

I did nothing after I installed Raspbian Stretch OS, and I have a 16 GB SD card. After the last command which took a long time, I see an error:

```
memory exhausted: can not allocate memory
makefile:3860: recipe for target 'lang/vid_gb_ap/libttsmimic_lang_vid_gb_ap_la-vid_gb_ap_cg_01_params.lo'failed
make[1]:*** [lang/vid_gb_ap/libttsmimic_lang_vid_gb_ap_la-vid_gb_ap_cg_01_params.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/mycroft-core/mimic'
makefile: 4111: recipe for target 'all-recursive'failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: oh, maybe for picroft you should either download the image already made for you, or use the **correct** source code https://github.com/MycroftAI/enclosure-picroft

Comment: perhaps mycroft for pi is cross compiled on a computer with more resources than the humble pi

Answer (score 0):

What you try cannot work. You are using `Raspbian Stretch` but *picroft* is build on `Raspbian Jessie` you can find it on https://github.com/MycroftAI/enclosure-picroft:

> The Picroft project is an enclosure for a stock Raspberry Pi connected to a speaker and basic USB microphone. This is built around a Raspbian Jessie Lite installation. The entire project is available as a pre-built micro-SD image ready to be burned and placed into a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: it works on Raspbian Stretch too.

Comment: @ali If you have solved your problem then please make an answer and share your experience with the community.

Comment: yes, i can't solve it completely but i know that tutorials for jessie can works for stretch too. for this problem i create a swapfile so i can install the dev file but when i release the swap file like when the memory is full the pi stops working.